# How to get a string out of (libgdx) json

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I really wonder how this would be done properly(*):

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("test.json");
Json json = new Json(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new StringWriter());
json.setWriter(writer);

json.writeObjectStart();
json.writeValue("name", "Testing");
json.writeObjectEnd();

file.writeString(..., false); // Here I am stuck
```

As you can see I want to **manually** (!) create a json object and write just one string in there. I do *not* want to use a serializer or anything the like for this matter.

In https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON there is a passage: Serialization Methods

In there the same is done. But how can I translate my Json to a String that can be written to a file? toString() is doing no good here.

(*) Once again, I want to **emphasize** I do NOT want to use a serializer in that case but build my own json-file from scratch. I'm totally aware of the problems and unmanagable-code this could lead to. Thank you!

Comment: I think the idea is that `JsonWriter` writes it directly to a stream, so instead of `new StringWriter()` you give it a file stream. You also then need to close your JsonWriter when you finish. I don't use Java so I can't give you a more solid answer, but [this question/answer combo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277529/android-jsonwriter-can-not-write-to-a-file) seems like it has enough info to provide the solution